# UWP/VB.Net - Change Bound Button Color Dependent on Variable

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager

I'm a little new to UWP.  I've spent two days looking for this answer and haven't come across the answer yet.  I know I could be approaching this completely wrong.  All help is appreciated!

I have a `SolidColorBrush`  `StaticResource` I've created in my App.xaml file:

```
    <Application.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colorClockStatus" Color="#cae0d5" />
    </Application.Resources>`
```

I've bound this brush to the Background property of a few buttons on a few pages.  For example, I bound the buttons it like this:

```
    <Button Background="{StaticResource colorClockStatus}"/>
```

That works great, the button backgrounds are the desired red. The problem comes in when I change the color of the `StaticResource`. The button color doesn't change.  If I open another page after the color change, the buttons on the new page will be green as desired, but I can't get a button on an already opened page to change color.

So here's the scenario.  When the user is 'ClockedIn', the bound buttons need to be green, and when the user clocks out, the bound buttons need to turn red and vise versa.  Here's the backend code in the App.xaml.vb file:

```
    Public Shared ClockedIn As Boolean = False

    Public Shared Sub SetClockedStatus(ByVal bClockedIn As Boolean)
        ClockedIn = bClockedIn
        With Application.Current
            If bClockedIn Then
                .Resources("colorClockStatus") = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 224, 213) 'Green
            Else
                .Resources("colorClockStatus") = Color.FromArgb(255, 227, 184, 179) 'Red
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

When the user taps the 'ClockIn' button, the above code is called.  I think I need a `INotifyPropertyChanged` event to let the UI know the `colorClockStatus` property changed and therefore needs to redraw the buttons, but I don't know how to do this with a `StaticResource`.  I've also have tried implementing a `VisualStateManager`, and create two `SaticResources` the button switches between (which seems like a better way), but I couldn't figure out how to set the trigger dependent on the Boolean 'ClockIn' variable, and then to implement the manager globally.

So how can I get the UI to change colors dependent on a Boolean variable?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I've been working on this some more and found an example using a `StateTriggerBase` class [here](https://ulrichbodentien.com/2015/11/21/inputmodetrigger-for-uwp-apps/#more-93).  I adapted this code to work for a Boolean property.  Below is my adapted class:

```
    Public Class ClockedInTrigger
        Inherits StateTriggerBase
        Private _ClockedIn As Boolean = False

        Public Property ClockedIn As Boolean
            Get
                Return _ClockedIn
            End Get
            Set
                If Not Value.Equals(_ClockedIn) Then
                    _ClockedIn = _ClockedIn
                    SetActive(ClockedIn = _ClockedIn)
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Then, instead of having just one `StaticResource`, I made two:

```
    <Application.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colorClockInLight" Color="#cae0d5" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colorClockOutLight" Color="#e3b8b3" />
    </Application.Resources>
```

Then I added a `VisualStateManager` to my MainPage to test it:

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ClockInStates">                
            <VisualState x:Name="vsClockedOut">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <local:ClockedInTrigger ClockedIn="False" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Background" Value="{StaticResource colorClockOutLight}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="vsClockedIn">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <local:ClockedInTrigger ClockedIn="True" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Background" Value="{StaticResource colorClockInLight}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I was really excited when I opened the program and the button was green! (By default, the button is red)   But to my disappointment, the button did not turn back red when I clocked out.  I used the debugger and the `SetActive(ClockedIn = _ClockedIn)` method is being called, but the UI doesn't change.  Do I have something wrong with my binding?  Is there some method I need to call to refresh the UI?

Comment: How do you change the active of `VisualState`? In the code you've posted, I didn't find method like `Current_SizeChanged` that can change the active of the the state trigger. Also I didn't find any binding in your code. I'm not sure what your `ClockedIn` is. Do you want to change `HamburgerButton.Background` according to a `bool` value that set in code-behind?

Comment: Thanks @JayZuo-MSFT!  `ClockedIn` is my `bool` property that is set in the code-behind to let the app know if the user is clocked in or not. The `ClockedInTrigger` class above inherits `StateTriggerBase`.  Through this inheritance, I was hoping the `<local:ClockedInTrigger ClockedIn="False" />` (binding?) would pick up the property change through the `SetActive` method in the `ClockedIn` property set. To answer the last question, yes I do want to change the background color according to a `bool` value, but my end goal would be to do this on multiple controls on multiple pages at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I think you can just take advantage of [StateTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.statetrigger.aspx) with a `InvertBoolConverter` like following:

XAML:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ClockInStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="vsClockedOut">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind ClockedIn, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Background" Value="{StaticResource colorClockOutLight}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="vsClockedIn">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind ClockedIn, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Background" Value="{StaticResource colorClockInLight}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

InvertBoolConverter:

```
Public Class InvertBoolConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim boolValue = CBool(value)
        Return Not boolValue
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Dim boolValue = CBool(value)
        Return Not boolValue
    End Function
End Class
```

Also you can try with [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers) which is a collection of custom visual state triggers. You can use [StateTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.statetrigger.aspx) and [IsFalseStateTrigger](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers/blob/master/src/WindowsStateTriggers/IsFalseStateTrigger.cs) instead of `InvertBoolConverter`. Besides, please note you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for `ClockedIn` property to make it work.

Comment: Thank you @JayZuo-MSFT!!